# Hiding I-94 data

Tags: usa, passports, i-94

I have made the mistake of showing someone my passport number in the past and they were able to track down exactly when I entered the US and from which airport.
If I get a new passport with a new passport number, that they aren’t aware of, would they still be able to see the information of when I enter/leave the US?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica I don’t think the suggested duplicate answers whether someone who **does not have** details of the OP’s **new** passport can still access their I-94. Are two (or more) passports linked in the system such that entering the *old* passport number would give access to travel undertaken using the *new* passport?

Comment: @Traveller That's a good point, thanks. I didn't make that connection. I'll withdraw my close-as-duplicate vote.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately a new passport number will not help. I just entered the number from my previous passport - which expired in 2014 - and although my current passport number is not displayed, my recent trips on it are.

So it is history of the traveller, not of the travel document, which is shown, and seemingly any valid document (that has been used for at least one trip, presumably) will unlock all such results. (Up to whatever the display limit is - despite supplying my 2004-2014 passport details, I can't actually see anything earlier than 2015.)